# Is the parent div element clicked with React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Any ideas on how can I trigger whether the user has clicked the parent element, but don't react to the click, if the user clicked inside the child div using ReactJS. As on the screenshot, I wish to "do something" if the user clicked in the black area, but don't react to clicks inside the white box

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an onClick on the child div and have it stop propagation:

```
const Example = () => {
  return (
    <div onClick={(e) => {
       // Handle the click for the outer area
    }}>
      <div onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>

      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```